# fstream in and out on nonexistent file

Tags: c++, fstream

Is it possible to open an fstream on a file that does not exist with both ios::in & ios::out without getting an error?

Comment: Don't forget to accept answers, or help answerers by letting them know whether you've tried their solutions (or fill them in with more details so they can tailor their answers.)

Answer (score 11):

To open an [`fstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream) on a file that does not exist for input and output (random access) without getting an error, you should provide the [*flags*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode) `fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::trunc` in the [`open`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open) (or [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringbuf/basic_stringbuf)) call. Since the file does not already exist, truncating the file at zero bytes is no drama.

You *may* want an error when opening a file that doesn't exist when specifying *only* `ios::in` since you'll never be able to read from the stream so failing early in this case will prevent surprise failures later on.

Comment: So why doesn't opening a file that doesn't exist through an object of class fstream throw an error? Example: fstream myfile; myfile.open ("this_file_doesn't_exist.txt");  //This doesn't throw any error.

Answer (score 5):

The answer to your question unfortunately is: "No", this is not possible in a single C++ statement.

Yes, many people will answer, that you can use the combined flags `fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::trunc`. But that answer is nonsense. `fstream::trunc` means, that the output file will be truncated to size zero upon opening. But then, why would you like to open an *empty* file for reading and writing? Except for the rare case, that you need a file as a temporary store for some of your application's data, that you will first write and later read back, there is no use for this flag combination.

Some people recommend to first try to open with `fstream::in | fstream::out` (and possible further flags like `fstream:app` or `fstream::binary` as needed) and then check the file's error status: If the file could not be opened, then re-try the open operation including `| fstream::trunc`. This solution has several caveats, however. For example, if your file system is mounted via NFS, the first attempt to open the file in read/write-mode might fail due to temporary network issues. If the second attempt (the one including the `fstream::trunc` flag) then succeeds, there goes your wounderful data, that you have collected so far.

The safe solution is to first open the file for appending only (which will create the file, if it doesn't exist, but will not truncate it) and then close it immediately and open it a second time in read-write mode. This can be achieved with the following code: Note, that an `ofstream` is first constructed and then immediately discarded.

```
std::string filename { "test.txt" };
(void) std::ofstream(filename, std::ostream::app);
std::fstream file(filename);
```

Alternatively, if you need further flags, like `binary`, use:

```
std::string filename { "test.txt" };
(void) std::ofstream(filename, std::ofstream::app | std::fstream::binary);
std::fstream file(filename, std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::binary);
```

I hope, that in C++25 (or whichever standard is next), they finally add a flag `std::fstream::create` to create non-existant output files, if read-write-mode is requested.

Comment: This worked correctly when I needed to create a file only when it did not exist before opening it.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <fstream> 

ofstream out("test", ios::out);
if(!out)
{
    cout << "Error opening file.\n";
    return 1;
}

ifstream in("test", ios::in);
if(!in)
{
    cout << "Error opening file.\n";
    return 1;
}
```

If an error occurs the message is displayed and one (1) is returned. However it is possible to compile and execute just `ofstream out("test", ios::out);` and `ifstream in("test", ios::in);` without any errors. Either way the file *test* is created.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  fstream f("test.txt", fstream::in | fstream::out);
  cout << f.fail() << endl;
  f << "hello" << endl;
  f.close();    
  return 0;
}
```

This code will print `1` and will not create "test.txt" file, if it does not exit. So it is not possible to open and fstream on a file that does not exist without getting an error.

Comment: Did you mean "filestr.fail()" and "filestr << "hello" << endl;"?!

Answer (score 0):

```
std::fstream f("test.txt", std::ios_base::out);
f.close(); //file now exists always
f.open("test.txt", fstream::in | std::ios_base::out);
//f is open for read and write without error
```

I haven't checked to guarantee that it will open without error, but I feel pretty confident that it should.