# c++ txt file not created by .open

Tags: c++

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<iomanip>
#include<cmath>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;    
int main()
{
    fstream afile;
    afile.open("example.txt");
    afile<<"Hi I am Unnat";
    afile.close();
    string line;
    ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while ( getline (myfile,line) )
        {
             cout << line << '\n';
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
    else cout << "Unable to open file"; 
    return 0;
}
```

The output i get here is always Unable to open file and when i check the folders I dont find example.txt
Please help.

Comment: Try `afile.open("example.txt", std::ios::out);`

Comment: Have you read the documentation on the function giving you trouble? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/open which calls http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open?

Comment: You check if the input file can be opened, but not the output file. Why is that?

Comment: @RSahu The default open-mode of [`std::fstream::open`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/open) is `ios_base::in|ios_base::out`, so `out` is already set.

Comment: @RSahu: That was my idea as well, though it [should work fine to open for both input and output even if the file doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896166/fstream-in-and-out-on-nonexistent-file#comment50923971_2896651). I'd be even more explicit myself, and use an `ofstream` instead of `fstream` so output-only was explicit.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Yeah, but [`ios_base::in` requires an existing file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8836041/560648). RSahu is correct — [you need `std::ios::out` and _not_ `std::ios::in`, to get automatic file creation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31483487/560648).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Do you have a standard citation for that? The comment I linked above indicates it (possibly compiler dependent) doesn't require an existing file. It seems rather odd to forbid opening a new file for input and output at once without explicitly truncating, since it's perfectly legitimate to create a file than you'll be writing and reading intermittently.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Yes, it's odd and annoying. But it _is_ so. It's inherited from UNIX. I'm not going to dig out all the standard references again - one of the aforelinked questions probably has what you're looking for.

Comment: have used fstream::out also but when I start the compiling with VS and start without debugging, it does not create a file. But running the .exe file creates the txt file but it still shows the output Unable to open file

Comment: @Unnatch: Are you actually listening to anyone?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I am sorry. I am a newbie. I am not able to get what people are saying on the comments. What I got was adding fstream::out would help and I tried that but when I want to open the file created, its not happening.

Comment: @Unnatch: Multiple links to information have been provided. Did you consider clicking on any of them?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I did but nothing was similar to my situation. I got my file created but now the code is not able to read the txt file.

Comment: That does not seem likely.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/open). I don't believe fstream::open creates the file if it doesn't exist. You need to use `afile.open("example.txt",fstream::out);` as referred to in [fstream won't create a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667530/fstream-wont-create-a-file)

Comment: I have used fstream::out also but when I start the compiling with VS and start without debugging, it does not create a file. But running the .exe file creates the txt file but it still shows the output Unable to open file