# Trying to read and write into files using c++, but not able to replace the substring correctly

Tags: c++

So, what I am trying to do is, read from a file and write into another.

```
std::ifstream fs;
fs.open ("/Users/aditimalladi/CLionProjects/file/log.txt");

string str_file;

std::ofstream fs2;
fs2.open ("/Users/aditimalladi/CLionProjects/file/log-copy.txt ");

if(!fs || !fs2)
{
    std::cout<<"ERROR";
    exit(0);
}

string str;

while(getline(fs,str))
{
    while(true) {
        std::cout<<"\n This is the string \n"<<str<<std::endl;
        size_t index = str.find("≠", index);

        if (index == std::string::npos) break;

        str.replace(index, 1, "-");
        index += 1;
        std::cout<<"\n This is the new replaced string \n"<<str<<std::endl;

    }
    fs2 << str << std::endl;
}

fs.close();
fs2.close();
```

What my end goal is to be able to read a line and replace that line in the same file after making some changes.But first I want this basic program to work before I move forward.

Comment: If one file is for reading, and the other for writing, then you need any of those flags since they are there by default.

Comment: Do you mean try removing the flags?

Comment: Not as a solution, but more as a side note.

Comment: Oh okay will do.

Comment: What is the question, and what is working other than expected? There is no `File` in your code. Do you mean that `log-copy.txt` is empty?

Comment: Nothing is being written into the target file. It is  empty. Yes I do mean log-copy.txt is empty

Comment: Are you sure you are reading anything? Why don't you try printing out content you are working on. I urge you to read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ .

Comment: [Dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2896166/5267751).

Comment: Thanks, will debug.

Comment: Figured that it isn't even opening the file

Comment: @AditiM Does `log.txt` exists in your current working directory ?

Comment: Yes it is. But I changed it to the full path and it works now. But the part where I have to replace the substrings doesn't work. So trying to fix that now.

Comment: Please note that the unicode character that you are trying to replace hasn't a size of 1: https://ideone.com/Vi8iwZ

Comment: Ya it's a non-ascii char, so needs more than 1! But what can i set it to to solve the problem. It doesnt work with 2, and with 3 it gets replaced in the first line of the file but not in the ones after that

Comment: Use the size of that non-ASCII char or regex, like in your first attempt: https://ideone.com/NN75Px

Comment: Changed the size, it works now. But for some strange reason regex didn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A problem in the snippet you posted is that you are trying to replace a string `"≠"`, which contains non-ASCII character that can be encoded with multiple bytes. So those lines:

```
size_t index = str.find("≠", index);
if (index == std::string::npos)
    break;
str.replace(index, 1, "-");
//      note this ^^^
```

Will replace only the first byte of the encoding, leaving the others.

You could use the correct size of the string to be replaced or rewrite your program using the regular expression library:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream fs {"/Users/aditimalladi/CLionProjects/file/log.txt"};
    std::ofstream fs2 {"/Users/aditimalladi/CLionProjects/file/log-copy.txt"};

    if(!fs || !fs2)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error, can't open files";
        exit(1);
    }

    std::regex a {"≠"};

    std::string line;
    while ( std::getline(fs, line) )
    {
        fs2 << std::regex_replace(line, a, "is not equal to") << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, this is what I tried originally but it never replaced anything. Then went ahead to try to match then replace. But it never matched the '≠' char in the first place.

Comment: @AditiM Please look at the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_replace) for std::regex_replace(3). In the first version of the snippet in your question you passed a string to it and then printed out the same string, but if you notice the function signature, strings are passed as const and the modified results are returned.